# Use classifiers with csv file as parameter X in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, classification, decision-tree

I have csv file, I took all data's that I will need later and wrote it in another file, and I took first column of original csv file and place it in variable Y. Now I just need to place my new csv file into variable X, but in good format so I can use DecisionTreeClassifier.

```
## Testing classifers ## 
df=pd.read_csv('G1.csv')

## Write datasets for X ##
#with open('G1.csv') as csvfile:
#    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
#    for row in readCSV:
#        temp = []
#        temp.append(row[4])
#        temp.append(row[5])
#        temp.append(row[6])
#        temp.append(row[7])
#        temp.append(row[8])
#        temp.append(row[9])
#        temp.append(row[10])
#        temp.append(row[11])
#        temp.append(row[12])
#        temp.append(row[13])
#        temp.append(row[14])
#        temp.append(row[15])
#        temp.append(row[16])
#        temp.append(row[17])
#        file = open('TestFile.csv', 'a+', newline ='')
#        with file:
#            write = csv.writer(file)
#            write.writerow(temp)
#        file.close()


## Write datasets for Y ##
Y = []
with open("G1.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
      Y.append(lines[0])

X = pd.read_csv('TestFile.csv')

P = [[2.94008,3.03106,-9.70609,6.09667,6.51713,0.0900986,NaN,NaN,NaN,0.792683,-1.70732,-1.82927,1008.96,31.54]]

#{Decision Tree Model}
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X,Y)
print ("\n1) Using Decision Tree Prediction is " + str(clf.predict(P)))
```

I am very new in Python so please don't judge for some syntax or something. I just have problem in converting my data's from file to good formatted variable X so I can use classifier.

TestFile.csv looks like

```
[2.77009,3.4261,-9.76116,6.93759,7.02769,0,-0.4245,-0.8415,2.6535,-0.609756,0.0609756,-0.182927,NaN,31.54]
```

and more cases like this one

Comment: Why are you writing to CSV?  Can't you just split X/y into separate dataframes?  There are lots of tutorials on how to do this online.

Comment: I tried to put in array but too much data for that, low memory. Same for dataframes then or?